# Docker Swarm and private IP

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

When I launch an app via docker I can publish the app on a  port specifying the IP.

Suppose that my server has two ip (private 192.168.0.2 and public 200.168.0.2), I can expose an app on the private ip with this command:

```
  docker run -it -p 192.168.0.2:80:80 nginx
```

How can I achieve something similar with docker swarm?

I guess I must create a docker network layer first, but I don't understand what the right syntax is.

Basically I would like to do something similar:

```
    docker network create \
      --driver overlay \
      --IP 192.168.0.2 \
      --IP 192.167.0.1 \
      private_net

    docker service create --replicas 2 \ 
    --network private_net --name my-web nginx
```

Where 192.168.0.2 and 192.167.0.1 are the IPs of the swarm cluster servers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swarm doesn't give the option to listen on a specific interface, it defaults to listen on all interfaces. This is an [open issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26696). Modifying overlay networks inside of docker will not change this behavior.